# IAR Source Browse Log errors

Tags: embedded, iar, nxp-microcontroller

My vendor provided IAR project for my MCU (*eww, *dep, etc)

I`m observing the error in Source Browser Log in IAR Embedded Workbench. Logs:

- Source Browse Log created.
- Launching source browser
- Failed to read the build nodes from the project.
- Failed to generate browse indexing file.
- Terminating source browser...
- **Unable to find pbw file**

Is the problem is the absence of the pbw file or something else?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved when the project you try to browse is marked as active. Right click in project name in workspace viewer and click 'Set as active' and rebuild the project.

Bests,

Imanol